# Strange behavior when mobile website is added to iPhone's "Home Screen" as a web app

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I have a mobile oriented web site which is not intended to be run as a mobile web app. When users add the mobile site to their iPhone's home screen links do not work and the site gets broken. 
Is there a way to detect a mobile site is running as an iPhone web app (from the Home Screen) and have it automatically launch in Safari instead? In other words, if the user "Add to Home Screen" to have it behave like a bookmark?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` from your HTML. Websites as home screen icons open in Safari unless specifically ordered not to using that meta tag.